# How do I make the font uniform in the bibliography and fix some bugs?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies

It was my first time using latex to write a thesis, and first, I would like to thank the community for its great help! I have learned a great skill!
I got my thesis back, and they really liked the style. One comment, however, was that bibliography didn't have uniform fonts (i.e. ISSN, DOI, and URL). I was wondering if there is a quick way to force the bibliography to have a uniform font/size. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\graphicspath{{./Chapters/Figures/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Load math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Set up the headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
%Allows first indent and loads setspace package to be used in different documents.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}

%Make cell space and scientific notation
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}


%Enables paragraph spacing. Saves the old indent value and restores it after loading the parskip package. Otherwise, you lose the indents. 
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Chapters/references.bib}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}


\frontmatter
\input{Chapters/titlePage.tex}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter{Abstract}
\input{Chapters/Abstract.tex}

\chapter{Résumé}
\input{Chapters/Resume.tex}

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\input{Chapters/Acknowledgment.tex}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Methodology}
\input{Chapters/Methodology.tex}

\chapter{Results}
\input{Chapters/Results.tex}

\chapter{Discussion}
\input{Chapters/Discussion.tex}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{Chapters/Conclusion.tex}

\appendix
\chapter{Tables}
\input{Chapters/Tables.tex}

\singlespacing
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this to your preamble:

```
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
```

or whatever font you want (may I suggest Old German?)

Comment: Thank you very much! How does it work? Moreover, some of my references leak a bit in the right margin... I guess there is no way to change that unless I remove some info?

Comment: Well, biblatex loads the `url` package, and I just looked at the documentation of url to see how to change the default font. For your leak problem, could you post a minimal example? Note you also can change the margin… but it might result in simply moving the problem to another reference.